How can I disable the shadow of the switch thumb in React Native?
On Android, the Switch Thumb shows a shadow by default when pressed down, which didn't match my UI design.
I tried changing the thumbColor property, but it still had a shadow.
Is there a way to disable this shadow?









System
Android14


React Native
0.74.1




